# Using 16-bit float slowing down computation

Tags: c#, .net

I was reading a suggestion for optimizing certain programs that suggested trying to use 16-bit floats in cases where higher levels of precision aren't needed.

This wasn't specific to C#, but I thought I would try using the Half struct added to .NET. However, upon making the changes where I could, my program actually became significantly slower - going from 30 seconds to do a full round of computations to 50 seconds. Is this because the Half struct just isn't well optimized, or am I just implementing it incorrectly.

**Edit**:
Since some examples were requested, this is the main part that's slowing down. I'm experimenting with making a convolutional neural network (I'm aware C# isn't the optimal language for that, this was just to get a better understanding of it). The part where things really slow down is during the backpropagation of the convolutional layers.

```cs
    protected void Backwards(FeatureMap input, Color[,] kernal, Color[,] dL_dK, FeatureMap dL_dP, FeatureMap dL_dPNext)
    {
        for (int strideX = 0; strideX < dL_dP.Width; strideX++)
        {
            for (int strideY = 0; strideY < dL_dP.Length; strideY++)
            {
                for (int kernalX = 0; kernalX < _kernalSize; kernalX++)
                {
                    for (int kernalY = 0; kernalY < _kernalSize; kernalY++)
                    {
                        int x = strideX * _stride + kernalX;
                        int y = strideY * _stride + kernalY;
                        Color dK = dL_dP[strideX, strideY] * input[x, y] * _invK2;
                        Color dP = dL_dP[strideX, strideX] * kernal[kernalX, kernalY] * _invK2;
                        dL_dK[kernalX, kernalY] += dK;
                        dL_dPNext[x, y] += dP;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < _kernalSize; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < _kernalSize; j++)
            {
                dL_dK[i, j] = dL_dK[i, j].Clamp(CLAMP);
            }
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < dL_dPNext.Width; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < dL_dPNext.Length; j++)
            {
                dL_dPNext[i, j] = dL_dPNext[i, j].Clamp(Half.One);
            }
        }
    }
```

A reference for the Color struct:

```cs
public readonly struct Color
{
    public Color(Half r, Half g, Half b)
    {
        R = r;
        G = g;
        B = b;
    }

    public Half B { get; }
    public Half G { get; }
    public Half Magnitude => Half.Sqrt(R * R + G * G + B * B);
    public Half SquareMagnitude => R * R + G * G + B * B;
    public Half R { get; }
    public static Color operator -(Color color1, Color color2)
    {
        return new Color(color1.R - color2.R, color1.G - color2.G, color1.B - color2.B);
    }

    public static Color operator -(Color color)
    {
        return new Color(-color.R, -color.G, -color.B);
    }

    public static Color operator *(Color color1, Color color2)
    {
        return new Color(color1.R * color2.R, color1.G * color2.G, color1.B * color2.B);
    }

    public static Color operator *(Color color, Half multiple)
    {
        return new Color(color.R * multiple, color.G * multiple, color.B * multiple);
    }

    public static Color operator *(Half multiple, Color color)
    {
        return new Color(color.R * multiple, color.G * multiple, color.B * multiple);
    }

    public static Color operator /(Color color1, Color color2)
    {
        return new Color(color1.R / color2.R, color1.G / color2.G, color1.B / color2.B);
    }

    public static Color operator +(Color color1, Color color2)
    {
        return new Color(color1.R + color2.R, color1.G + color2.G, color1.B + color2.B);
    }

    public Color Clamp(Half val)
    {
        return new Color(R > val ? val : R < -val ? -val : R, G > val ? val : G < -val ? -val : G, B > val ? val : B < -val ? -val : B);
    }
}
```

FeatureMap is just a 2D array of Color types.

Comment: Can you provide a code example of the computations are you trying to make? How are you casting the float type to Half type?

Comment: I can try, but I'm not sure if it will be easily comprehensible, as I'm working with images, so my code primarily refers to Color which is a struct containing the RGB data as Half types. I'm primarily just doing a number of arithmatic operations on it, and once the images are loaded in, their pixel data is converted to the Color type. From that point onwards there's no further float/Half conversion.

Comment: Side note: it is always good idea to provide source for your "was reading..." remark. I.e. 'I was reading [Introducing the Half type!](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/introducing-the-half-type/) which said " One of the primary use cases of the Half type is to save on storage space where the computed result does not need to be stored with full precision."` or something like that. Right now the question contains no reasoning why Half (float16) should be *faster* than native `float` or `double` types on a regular CPU...

Comment: ... There are indeed plenty of articles stating that GPU-based calculations can be much faster with float16 - (https://www.bing.com/search?q=performance+float16+vs+float32), but that makes sense as shorter float values are common there for ages and less memory is critical there for performance... unlike what you trying here.

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov TBH I'd be surprised if 32-bit is faster than 64-bit on a modern processor either. I was under the impression the JITter internally just uses 64-bit and then downcasts

Answer (score 1):

From this [article](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/introducing-the-half-type/)

> More formally, the Half type is defined as a base-2 16-bit **interchange** format meant to support the exchange of floating-point data between implementations

I.e. it is meant to allow you to handle data produced by some other system, likely AI code that runs on a GPU. It is not intended for doing any kind of math in regular C# code.

Regular consumer CPUs do not have support for arithmetic on 16 bit floats. But this may change in the near future. Currently any operation, including conversion operations, will have a fairly hefty performance penalty since the CPU would need to move the individual bits to their corresponding positions in a 32 bit float before doing any operation. This will likely outweigh any possible benefit due to more compact storage.

GPUs and several specialized AI accelerators do have direct hardware support for 16 bit floats, in various different formats. So they do not suffer from this problem.

Comment: Thank you. I figured that might be the case, but I simply couldn't find very much on the Half type itself. I did read that article, but must have skimmed over it being specific for GPU. The article I was reading did seem to infer that you were using a GPU, but I have not implemented that yet.